# How use nginx variable $cookie with point cookie, like "foo.bar"

Tags: variables, cookies, nginx

How use Nginx variable **$cookie_** with dot (point) cookie, like **"foo.bar"**
If i write **"$cookie_foo.bar"** in access log file i have **"-.bar"**

Answer (score 10):

The `WONTFIX` comment on @aorth's bug's resolution is *supremely unhelpful*, and I'm still flabbergasted that Nginx just refuses to accommodate [perfectly legal characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#Directives) in cookie names. They *could* just replace the "magic" nginx chars in cookie names with underscores, or make you escape "magic" chars, or any number of other ways people have already solved similar problems.

It's not rocket surgery, Nginx.

Anyhow, this is how I wound up extracting the value for a cookie named `foo.lang` that my devs put in a critical app:

```
map $http_cookie $foo_lang_cookie {
    default "";
    "~foo\.lang=(?<foo_lang>[^;]+)" $foo_lang;
}
```

Hopefully my hours of fruitless Googling and beating my head against the wall can benefit other lost souls who find their way here.

Comment: much appreciated 

Answer (score 1):

I think I've just hit this exact issue trying to use a cookie of the form `app.current.user.id` with both nginx 1.6.2 and 1.7.9. I've [filed a bug in nginx](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/707).